# NGINX SEO Rewrite

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, seo, server

I'm trying to rewrite some urls for SEO with NGINX.The files are being downloaded as-is.

website.com/games - Works

website.com/games/game-title/1 - Works

website.com/games/game-title/1/news - Downloads PHP File

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/games?$ /games.php last;
  }         

  location /games/ {        
    rewrite ^/games/([^/]+?)/([0-9]+)? /game.php?id=$2 break; 
    rewrite ^/games/([^/]+?)/([0-9]+)?/news /game.php?id=$2&show=news last;        
  }
```

Comment: From what I see, both last urls should download php. But anyway, you've messed up with `break` and `last` flags.

Comment: It downloads the php file to my PC's hardrive in plain view. Big security risk.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it that way:

```
rewrite ^/games/? /games.php;

location /games/ {
    rewrite ^/games/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/news /game.php?id=$2&show=news last;
    rewrite ^/games/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)      /game.php?id=$2           last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    ... php stuff ...
}
```